# Refesh listbox from xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

In my WPF MVVM application I am currently trying to move from button event handlers to Commands.

I have a list box that represents the list of contacts, this data is bound to my viewmodel.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ContactListBox" Margin="5" BorderThickness="2"
      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
      SelectionMode="Single">
          <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowingFavorites}" Value="True">
                               <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=FavContactList}" />
                               <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentFavContact}" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsShowingFavorites}" Value="False">
                               <Setter Property="ItemsSource"  Value="{Binding Path=ContactList}" />
                               <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentContact}" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
         </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

I also have a button that adds new contact:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="AddFavs" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" Click="AddFavs_Click" >
```

Right now I want to get rid of my `AddFavs_Click`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for Add click event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Not used</param>
    /// <param name="e">Not used</param>
    private void AddFavs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.AddFavorites();
        ContactListBox.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

with AddFavourites command. 
So far I can move AddFavorites(); to be a command, however, my view model doesn't have access to the view, so I am unable to do ContactListBox.Items.Refresh(); in my view model, and that's why when new Contact is added, ContactListBox is not being updated properly.

My guess was to somehow trigger Item.Refresh() from XAML, but I haven't found solution yet.

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes, I do. However when I do RaisePropertyChanged, it doesn't update my listbox immediately, but only when I click on some other item on the list, and then it updates.

Comment: Try to use `ItemsSource="{...., UpdateTriggerSource=PropertyChanged}" `.  If that doesn't work, can you edit your question to include how you tried adding AddRemoveFavs as a Command?

Comment: Sure. Will do in a sec.

Comment: If `ContactList` is an `ObservableCollection`, then you shouldn't have to do anything, adding/removing an item to `ObservableCollection` will update the UI accordingly.

Comment: NETScape, Unfortunately ItemsSource="{...., UpdateTriggerSource=PropertyChanged}" didn't help, however with this change, when I am trying to use mouse to scroll over all items in the list it skips the one contact that I just removed.

Comment: I would envision this control's DataContext to be ContactsViewModel, is that an accurate statement?

Answer (score 1):

So many times I have seen a WPF developer *trying to save on XAML* and implementing some ridiculous *data-sharing view or control* and then coming here and saying *what's happening here?*. You're all making your life much more difficult to save on one small XAML file?? I'm sure you'll say that that's *not* what you're doing, but either way, my advice would be the same.

Don't share views with different view models and especially don't share UI controls with different data sources. If you were really writing an application using the MVVM pattern, then as @sthotakura mentioned, you wouldn't need to update the UI at all... you'd make a change to *the data* and *the UI would automatically update*, thanks to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

You'll also find it a lot simpler hiding and showing additional `DataGrid` controls that are already set up in XAML then trying to change the data bound sources at run time.

Comment: Really appreciate the feedback, and I absolutely do agree with your points, however I wasn't the designer of application, so have to work with what I have.

Comment: Making the change to go code-behind events to Commands is a change that is considered worth it.  It also follows MVVM closer than using a code-behind event...

Comment: In addition to `INotifyPropertyChanged`, there is also `INotifyCollectionChanged`, mentioned above in a comment by @sthotakura. `ObservableCollection` implements this, and simply changing the collection should cause the listbox to automatically refresh itself.

Comment: Ah, just discussed all the points with people who designed it, and got to the point to leave some event handlers as it is, if they are causing too many problems during moving to commanding